# This weird windows folder C:\users\%userprofile%\documents\afterSentDocuments

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

just activated the view hidden files option of file explorer and found this folder that contains some subfolders like this screenshot here :
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yyF0.png)

when I click on some random subfolder it shows some pdf and txt files and .DOC files

I tried to access a txt files and it displays the following content :

" Still court no small think death so an wrote. Incommode necessary no it behaviour convinced distrusts an unfeeling he. Could death since do we hoped is in. Exquisite no my attention extensive. The determine conveying moonlight age. Avoid for see marry sorry child. Sitting so totally forbade hundred to.
Consulted perpetual of pronounce me delivered. Too months nay end change relied who beauty wishes matter. Shew of john real park so rest we on. Ignorant dwelling occasion ham for thoughts overcame off her consider. Polite it elinor is depend. His not get talked effect worthy barton. Household shameless incommode at no objection behaviour. Especially do at he possession insensible sympathize boisterous it. Songs he on an widen me event truth. Certain law age brother sending amongst why covered.
You vexed shy mirth now noise. Talked him people valley add use her depend letter. Allowance too applauded now way something recommend. Mrs age men and trees jokes fancy. Gay pretended engrossed eagerness continued ten. Admitting day him contained unfeeling attention mrs out.
New had happen unable uneasy. Drawings can followed improved out sociable not. Earnestly so do instantly pretended. See general few civilly amiable pleased account carried. Excellence projecting is devonshire dispatched remarkably on estimating. Side in so life past. Continue indulged speaking the was out horrible for domestic position. Seeing rather her you not esteem men settle genius excuse. Deal say over you age from. Comparison new ham melancholy son themselves.
Way nor furnished sir procuring therefore but. Warmth far manner myself active are cannot called. Set her half end girl rich met. Me allowance departure an curiosity ye. In no talking address excited it conduct. Husbands debating replying overcame blessing he it me to domestic.
Speedily say has suitable disposal add boy. On forth doubt miles of child. Exercise joy man children rejoiced. Yet uncommonly his ten who diminution astonished. Demesne new manners savings staying had. Under folly balls death own point now men. Match way these she avoid see death. She whose drift their fat off.
Not him old music think his found enjoy merry. Listening acuteness dependent at or an. Apartments thoroughly unsatiable terminated sex how themselves. She are ten hours wrong walls stand early. Domestic perceive on an ladyship extended received do. Why jennings our whatever his learning gay perceive. Is against no he without subject. Bed connection unreserved preference partiality not unaffected. Years merit trees so think in hoped we as.
Can curiosity may end shameless explained. True high on said mr on come. An do mr design at little myself wholly entire though. Attended of on stronger or mr pleasure. Rich four like real yet west get. Felicity in dwelling to drawings. His pleasure new steepest for reserved formerly disposed jennings.
Is allowance instantly strangers applauded discourse so. Separate entrance welcomed sensible laughing why one moderate shy. We seeing piqued garden he. As in merry at forth least ye stood. And cold sons yet with. Delivered middleton therefore me at. Attachment companions man way excellence how her pianoforte.
Lose eyes get fat shew. Winter can indeed letter oppose way change tended now. So is improve my charmed picture exposed adapted demands. Received had end produced prepared diverted strictly off man branched. Known ye money so large decay voice there to. Preserved be mr cordially incommode as an. He doors quick child an point at. Had share vexed front least style off why him.
Needed feebly dining oh talked wisdom oppose at. Applauded use attempted strangers now are middleton concluded had. It is tried ?no added purse shall no on truth. Pleased anxious or as in by viewing forbade minutes prevent. Too leave had those get being led weeks blind. Had men rose from down lady able. Its son him ferrars proceed six parlors. Her say projection age announcing decisively men. Few gay sir those green men timed downs widow chief. Prevailed remainder may propriety can and.
Surrounded affronting favourable no mr. Lain knew like half she yet joy. Be than dull as seen very shot. Attachment ye so am travelling estimating projecting is. Off fat address attacks his besides. Suitable settling mr attended no doubtful feelings. Any over for say bore such sold five but hung.
An do on frankness so cordially immediate recommend contained. Imprudence insensible be literature unsatiable do. Of or imprudence solicitude affronting in mr possession. Compass journey he request on suppose limited of or. She margaret law thoughts proposal formerly. Speaking ladyship yet scarcely and mistaken end exertion dwelling. All decisively dispatched instrument particular way one devonshire. Applauded she sportsman explained for out objection.
Sense child do state to defer mr of forty. Become latter but nor abroad wisdom waited. Was delivered gentleman acuteness but daughters. In as of whole as match asked. Pleasure exertion put add entrance distance drawings. In equally matters showing greatly it as. Want name any wise are able park when. Saw vicinity judgment remember finished men throwing.
Dwelling and speedily ignorant any steepest. Admiration instrument affronting invitation reasonably up do of prosperous in. Shy saw declared age debating ecstatic man. Call in so want pure rank am dear were. Remarkably to continuing in surrounded diminution on. In unfeeling existence objection immediate repulsive on he in. Imprudence comparison uncommonly me he difficulty diminution resolution. Likewise proposal differed scarcely dwelling as on raillery. September few dependent extremity own continued and ten prevailed attending. Early to weeks we could.
Lose john poor same it case do year we. Full how way even the sigh. Extremely nor furniture fat questions now provision incommode preserved. Our side fail find like now. Discovered travelling for insensible partiality unpleasing impossible she. Sudden up my excuse to suffer ladies though or. Bachelor possible marianne directly confined relation as on he.
Civility vicinity graceful is it at. Improve up at to on mention perhaps raising. Way building not get formerly her peculiar. Up uncommonly prosperous sentiments simplicity acceptance to so. Reasonable appearance companions oh by remarkably me invitation understood. Pursuit elderly ask perhaps all.
Is we miles ready he might going. Own books built put civil fully blind fanny. Projection appearance at of admiration no. As he totally cousins warrant besides ashamed do. Therefore by applauded acuteness supported affection it. Except had sex limits county enough the figure former add. Do sang my he next mr soon. It merely waited do unable.
Old there any widow law rooms. Agreed but expect repair she nay sir silent person. Direction can dependent one bed situation attempted. His she are man their spite avoid. Her pretended fulfilled extremely education yet. Satisfied did one admitting incommode tolerably how are.
Drawings me opinions returned absolute in. Otherwise therefore sex did are unfeeling something. Certain be ye amiable by exposed so. To celebrated estimating excellence do. Coming either suffer living her gay theirs. Furnished do otherwise daughters contented conveying attempted no. Was yet general visitor present hundred too brother fat arrival. Friend are day own either lively new. "

I tried to reorginize them via chatgpt but they made no sense, anybody has an idea about all of this out of curiosity.

enlight us please.

much appreciated.

PS : Sorry for the long boring text.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Clearly found online on search for "windows folder aftersentdocuments": created by SentinelOne

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature in SentinelOne.
This is part of the malware and ransomware detection.

https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/pl56da/strange_hidden_folder_in_users_folder_on_windows/

Comment: References would help